# PopUp control does not move with the Window, while moving the window after we resize it

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, wpf-controls, wpf-positioning

I am facing one issue with the WPF popup control.
When we resize the window and move it, **PopUp control remains at same position at which it was open previously and does not move with the window**.
So what is the solution for this issue.
please provide code snippet for the solution if any. Thanks :)

**Xaml code for popup control is as follows:**

```
<Popup x:Name="popNonTopMostPopup" Height="200" Width="220" AllowsTransparency="True" Placement="Right">
            <Grid Background="Transparent">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <fa:FontAwesome Grid.Column="0" Icon="Play" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Rotation="180" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0 7 -2 0" />
                <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="LightGray" Background="Black" CornerRadius="5" Height="200" Width="200">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Button x:Name="btnCustomPopup" Click="btnCustomPopup_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="Transparent" Foreground="LightGray" BorderBrush="Transparent" Grid.Row="0">
                            <StackPanel Margin="0">
                                <fa:FontAwesome Icon="Close" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                        <Label x:Name="lblName" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="LightGray"/>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label x:Name="lblDueDate" Foreground="LightGray" Content="Fristdatum: " Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Visibility="Hidden"></Label>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtDueDate" Foreground="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Hidden"></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                        <Separator Grid.Row="3"></Separator>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="txtComments" Foreground="LightGray" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Grid.Row="4" Margin="10 10 10 10"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </Popup>
```

**We have icons on map on click of which pop up control is displayed.Code for click event is as follows.**

```
void pin_MouseLeftButtonDownForOrder(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
      // set the placement target of popup as pin mapicon
      popNonTopMostPopup.PlacementTarget = orderIcon;
      popNonTopMostPopup.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Comment: Provide Code pls

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I updated the question with the code snippet @Peter

Comment: I dont think that there is a super easy solution to this. But here is a Framework that is working pretty good - I am using it too in my current project. It provides features that u might wanna have :) ! https://github.com/punker76/MahApps.Metro.SimpleChildWindow . It is aviable in the nuget store - so pretty convenient.

Comment: Also it is open source - why not check out how they do it ?

Comment: Thanks :)..yes i will check this solution @Peter...but also is there any other solution you have then please suggest that...because changing the control could be the last thing i can do